# Box2d: One default static body created with world? Purpose?

Tags: box2d

If I set up a new world, and iterate through the bodies in it without creating any bodies first, there appears to be one static body existing in the new world. Where does that body come from, and why does it exist?

I'm using box2dweb, the javascript version of box2d. If you run the following code in an html file you'll get a console log returning the m_type of any bodies in the world. It will return a zero indicating one static body exists (m_type of 0 = static, 1 = kinematic, 2 = dynamic)

```
var b2Vec2 = Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2;
var b2World = Box2D.Dynamics.b2World;

var world = new b2World(new b2Vec2(0, 10), true);

for(var body = world.GetBodyList();body;body = body.GetNext()){
   console.log(body.m_type);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the source (https://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/source/browse/trunk/Box2D.js#5699) at line 5717 there you can see one body is being made as a 'ground body'. It's often handy to have a body like that (most commonly, to use as one body of a mouse joint when dragging things around). In my opinion it's a bit of a no-no for the engine to go making bodies like that, but it seems to also be used in the pulley joint creation for some reason that I don't quite follow.